# Members Self activation

Tags: members

I am using User from Solspace.

Am i right in thinking if i set "members" to self activation via email in the control panel when someone goes to register using the form below they should technically be sent an activation email to the email they submit on the form?

Am i missing a trick because everytime i do this the gmail account that i register with goes throough on the control panel and status is pending however the email i used in the registration never gets sent an email.

```
{exp:user:register
return="template_group/template"
}

<p>Username:
    <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
<p>Screen Name:
    <input type="text" name="screen_name" /></p>
<p>Email Address:
    <input type="text" name="email" /></p>

<p>Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
<p>Confirm Password:
    <input type="password" name="password_confirm" /></p>

{if captcha}
<p>Please enter in the word you see below:
    <input type="text" name="captcha" /></p>
<p>{captcha}</p>
{/if}

<p><input type="checkbox" name="accept_terms" value="y" />
    Accept Terms?</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

{if no_results}
<p>You're currently logged in, and must be logged
    out to view this form.</p>
{/if}

{/exp:user:register}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know for certain that the activation email isn't sent or is it not arriving? If it's not arriving then it could be down to a number of reasons ranging from spam filters to a problem with your site's email set up.

Comment: Thanks for reply again, i dont know for certain but it gets stored properly in the backend etc just no email to activate is sent out so aslong as i dont have to do anything else funky in the control panel then i guess it will be server related? its a new install of the latest expression engine.

Comment: Was down to the email i had in my email configuration wasn't an email on my server, tried with on my server and now all works fine. Nice one. Thanks again.